# DataTemplate based on DataType not working and causing other problems

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a `TabControl` with its `ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of type object. The only reason I do this is so that I can put both Property and Tennant (Please ignore the misspelling) classes into this list. My `TabControl` needs to have two different tabs based off the type. Here's what I have so far:

```
<view:CustomTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding OpenTabs}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Tabs">
    <view:CustomTabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tennant}">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Property}">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid MinWidth="350">
                    <!-- All of the stuff that works for the Property layout in here -->
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </view:CustomTabControl.Resources>
</view:CustomTabControl>
```

It's working perfectly with the Property class, but not the Tennant class. Also, I have a have to `ListBox`'s on the side. One for Properties and one for Tennants. When I add a Tennant to the tennant's list, it shows up as there, but doesn't display the name of the tennant which I have specified like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="10,5" Text="Properties" FontSize="16"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="propertiesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Property}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock Margin="10,5" Text="Tennants" FontSize="16"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="tennantsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Tennants, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tennant}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As far as I can see, the Tennant class is almost identical to the Property class, except for of course the information it stores, but it almost seems like nothing is binding properly to the Tennant object. What do I need to change? Is there something wrong with my Tennant class? Or is there something wrong in my xaml? Here is the Tennant class, paraphrased, for reference:

```
[Serializable]
public class Tennant : ISerializable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool current;
    private string name;
    private string phone;
    private string email;
    private string occupation;
    public bool Current { get { return current; } set { current = value; OnPropertyChanged("Current"); } }
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    public string Phone { get { return phone; } set { phone = value; OnPropertyChanged("Phone"); } }
    public string Email { get { return email; } set { email = value; OnPropertyChanged("Email"); } }
    public string Occupation { get { return occupation; } set { occupation = value; OnPropertyChanged("Occupation"); } }

    public Tennant()
    {

    }

    public Tennant(bool current, string name, string phone, string email, string occupation)
    {
        this.Current = current;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Phone = phone;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Occupation = occupation;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "" + Current + " " + Name + " " + Phone + " " + Email + " " + Occupation;
    }

    public Tennant(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.Current = (bool)info.GetValue("Current", typeof(bool));
        this.Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
        this.Phone = (string)info.GetValue("Phone", typeof(string));
        this.Email = (string)info.GetValue("Email", typeof(string));
        this.Occupation = (string)info.GetValue("Occupation", typeof(string));

    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Current", this.Current);
        info.AddValue("Name", this.Name);
        info.AddValue("Phone", this.Phone);
        info.AddValue("Email", this.Email);
        info.AddValue("Occupation", this.Occupation);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here's the Property Object just for reference:

```
public class Property : ISerializable
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    // ...

    public Property()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public bool hasPhotos()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool hasTennant()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void addTennant(Tennant tennant)
    {
        tennants.Add(tennant);
    }

    public void addPhoto(Photo photo)
    {
        photos.Add(photo);
    }

    public void addIssue(Problem issue)
    {
        issues.Add(issue);
    }

    public Property(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What is there wrong in my code? Because after hours of searching I can't find anything. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 2:** I added the rest of the Tennant class. Also, my tabs are custom tabs that have a close button, and when I click on one of the tennant listboxitems next to the tabcontrol, it opens up an empty closable tab. The Property listboxitems on the side open up a full closable tab. Then, I can close the Property tabs, but not the Tennant tabs. Here's my code for adding to the OpenTabs object ObservableCollection:

```
// Inside the Constructor
OpenTabs = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ListBoxItem),
    ListBoxItem.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnMouseLeftButtonDown));

private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem selected = sender as ListBoxItem;
    try
    {
        string t = (selected.Content as Property).title;
        Property cur = selected.Content as Property;
        OpenProperty(cur);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException nre)
    {
        Tennant cur = selected.Content as Tennant;
        OpenTennant(cur);
    }
}

// This method opens a new tab with a Property's details in it
private void OpenProperty(Property property)
{
    this.HomeView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    this.TabbedView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    MainWindow.OpenTabs.Add(property);
    this.Tabs.SelectedIndex = MainWindow.OpenTabs.IndexOf(property);
}

// This method opens a new tab with a Tennant's details in it
private void OpenTennant(Tennant tennant)
{
    this.HomeView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    this.TabbedView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    MainWindow.OpenTabs.Add(tennant);
    this.Tabs.SelectedIndex = MainWindow.OpenTabs.IndexOf(tennant);
}
```

Hope that helps. Ask if you want more.

**Edit 3:** Now I've added context to the xaml, and also added `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the Tennant class which is updated above. I also forgot to add the fact that both `DataTemplates are separate. As in separated by a GridSplitter.

**Edit 4:** I'm still looking for answers to this question, as my problem still exists, even though I have implemented, to the best of my abilities every answer that has been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `Tennant` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Otherwise, changes made within the backing class won't be reflected in the UI, which sounds like it could be your issue.

Comment: That's not implemented in Property though... How come?

Comment: @EthanBrouwer There's not enough to see - but depending on how/when the data is set, it may cause it to behave differently.

Comment: What else do you need? And what do you mean when it is set? Sorry. I'm not an expert.

Comment: Post all the code, ObservableCollection notifies when items changes, not when their properties change (role of INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: @Aybe I posted more code. Is that enough? What else do you want?

Comment: @ReedCopsey I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, but I don't know if I did it right, and it also still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You're showing two different implicit `DataTemplates` for `Tennant` but not where it is that you're declaring them. If they're both ending up in scope together (or neither in scope) you could be getting the one that you're not expecting (or no template).

Comment: I added context because I don't think that that's the problem.